# ROS Stage in Fuerte on 12.04: Stage controller tutorial only for 3.x.x

Tags: simulation, simulator-stage, stage, stageros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get the controller tutorial working for ROS Stage 4.x.x? I ran into the following problems when attempting to get the tutorial working though it is not meant for my version of Stage. Link to tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers)

First Error:

```
paresh@paresh-9:~/ros_workspace$ rosrun stage stageros `rospack find stage_controllers`/world/roomba-wander.world

 [Loading /home/paresh/ros_workspace/stage_controllers/world/roomba-wander.world][Image "bitmaps/roomba-stage.png"]
err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
err: Unknown model type laser in world file. (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
```

Fix: roomba-wander.world: ln35 col18: laser to ranger

Second Error:

```
paresh@paresh-9:~/ros_workspace$ rosrun stage stageros `rospack find stage_controllers`/world/roomba-wander.world
 [Loading /home/paresh/ros_workspace/stage_controllers/world/roomba-wander.world][Image "bitmaps/roomba-stage.png"]warn: lookup of model name roomba.ranger:1: no matching name (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc GetModel)
warn: Model roomba.ranger:1 not found (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/model.cc GetChild)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't know how to fix the second error. Any information would help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38265/ros-stage-in-fuerte-on-12.04:-stage-controller-tutorial-only-for-3.x.x/) by [paresh471](https://answers.ros.org/users/2797/paresh471/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticket opened [Ticket #5486 (new defect)](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5486)

---

Originally posted by [paresh471](https://answers.ros.org/users/2797/paresh471/) with karma: 86 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone would need to do some significant updates.

So your request does not get lost, I recommend [opening a defect ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=stage&type=defect&&stage) for the ROS stage package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-07-09**:
@joq Yep ! I agree

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See
http://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/
and
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5461

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paresh471](https://answers.ros.org/users/2797/paresh471/) on 2012-07-11**:
I did exactly that to remove the first error, but the second error is the crux of the matter.